# Not able to get the cublasSgelsbatched function to work

Tags: c++, cuda, cublas

I'm currently trying to get the cublasSgelsbatched (https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html) version to work. I started by first making a small test case to see what parameters are needed exactly and how they need to be inputted. However after much trial and error I still can't get it to work, I get a status return of 13, which corresponds to CUBLAS_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED which is a very vague error, also I tried some other cublas testcases and they seem to be working fine. I also tested the input matrix in MATlab, which does have a LS solution.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include "cublas_v2.h"

#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    //init id, handle and stat
    int id = cudaGetDevice(&id);
    cublasHandle_t m_cuBLAS;
    cublasStatus_t stat;

    // create handle
    stat = cublasCreate(&m_cuBLAS);

    //params
    const int C = 3; 
    const int M = 2;
    long lda = C;
    long ldb = M;

    //init variables
    float *Amat, *Ymat, *Xmat;
    float *gAmat, *gYmat;

    //allocate mem
    Amat = (float*) malloc(M * C * sizeof(float));
    Ymat = (float*) malloc(C *  sizeof(float));
    Xmat = (float*) malloc(M *  sizeof(float));

    srand(100);

    for (int i = 0; i < C * M; i++) {
        Amat[i] = rand() % 10 + 1;
        Amat[i] = (float)Amat[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < C; i++) {
        Ymat[i] =  rand() % 10 + 1;
        Ymat[i] = (float)Ymat[i];
    }

    //allocate mem
    cudaMalloc( &gAmat, M * C * sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc( &gYmat, C * sizeof(float));

    //copy mem
    cudaMemcpy(gAmat, Amat, M * C * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(gYmat, Ymat, C * 1 * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    //init info params
    int info = 0;
    int devInfoArray[1] = { 0 };

    //Synchronize (not necesarry I think, but just to test)
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    

    //run cublas
    cublasStatus_t status = cublasSgelsBatched(m_cuBLAS,
        CUBLAS_OP_N,
        C,
        M,
        1,
        &gAmat,
        lda, //or 1
        &gYmat,
        lda,
        &info,
        NULL,
        1);
    
    //Output info
    std::cout << "status = " << status << std::endl;
    std::cout << "info = " << info << std::endl;
    std::cout << "devInfoArray = " << devInfoArray[0] << std::endl;

    cudaMemcpy(Xmat, gYmat, C * 1 * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    //Output printed
    std::cout << Xmat[0] << ", " << Xmat[1] << ", " << Xmat[2] << std::endl;

    //free memory
    free(Amat);
    free(Ymat);
    free(Xmat);

    cudaFree(gAmat);
    cudaFree(gYmat);

    //destory handle
    cublasDestroy(m_cuBLAS);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm on Windows 10 running in MVS using CUDA 9.0

I'd really appreciate some help

Comment: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#cublas-lt-t-gt-gelsBatched -- "Aarray is an array of pointers to matrices stored in column-major format". I don't see any array of pointers to matrices in your code, do you?

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, you are not creating a proper array of pointers on the device.  The [batched function](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#cublas-lt-t-gt-gelsBatched) works with an array of pointers *that lives in device memory*, for the data parameters, for example:

> Aarray    **device**    input/output        array of pointers to  array, with each array of dim. m x n with lda>=max(1,m). Matrices Aarray[i] should not overlap; otherwise, undefined behavior is expected.

Passing for example `&gAmat` seems to satisfy the type requirement, but *that pointer does not point to device memory*.

The following modifications to your code focused on proper handling of `gAmat` and `gYmat` seem to run without error for me:

```
$ cat t130.cu
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cublas_v2.h>

#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    //init id, handle and stat
    int id = cudaGetDevice(&id);
    cublasHandle_t m_cuBLAS;
    cublasStatus_t stat;

    // create handle
    stat = cublasCreate(&m_cuBLAS);

    //params
    const int C = 3;
    const int M = 2;
    long lda = C;
    long ldb = M;

    //init variables
    float *Amat, *Ymat, *Xmat;
    float *gAmat, *gYmat;

    //allocate mem
    Amat = (float*) malloc(M * C * sizeof(float));
    Ymat = (float*) malloc(C *  sizeof(float));
    Xmat = (float*) malloc(M *  sizeof(float));

    srand(100);

    for (int i = 0; i < C * M; i++) {
        Amat[i] = rand() % 10 + 1;
        Amat[i] = (float)Amat[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < C; i++) {
        Ymat[i] =  rand() % 10 + 1;
        Ymat[i] = (float)Ymat[i];
    }

    //allocate mem
    cudaMalloc( &gAmat, M * C * sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc( &gYmat, C * sizeof(float));

    //copy mem
    cudaMemcpy(gAmat, Amat, M * C * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(gYmat, Ymat, C * 1 * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    float **ggAmat, **ggYmat;
    cudaMalloc(&ggAmat, sizeof(float*));
    cudaMalloc(&ggYmat, sizeof(float*));
    cudaMemcpy(ggAmat, &gAmat, sizeof(float*), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(ggYmat, &gYmat, sizeof(float*), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    //init info params
    int info = 0;
    int devInfoArray[1] = { 0 };

    //Synchronize (not necesarry I think, but just to test)
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();


    //run cublas
    cublasStatus_t status = cublasSgelsBatched(m_cuBLAS,
        CUBLAS_OP_N,
        C,
        M,
        1,
        ggAmat,
        lda, //or 1
        ggYmat,
        lda,
        &info,
        NULL,
        1);

    //Output info
    std::cout << "status = " << status << std::endl;
    std::cout << "info = " << info << std::endl;
    std::cout << "devInfoArray = " << devInfoArray[0] << std::endl;

    cudaMemcpy(Xmat, gYmat, C * 1 * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    //Output printed
    std::cout << Xmat[0] << ", " << Xmat[1] << ", " << Xmat[2] << std::endl;

    //free memory
    free(Amat);
    free(Ymat);
    free(Xmat);

    cudaFree(gAmat);
    cudaFree(gYmat);

    //destory handle
    cublasDestroy(m_cuBLAS);

    return 0;
}
$ nvcc -o t130 t130.cu -lcublas
t130.cu(15): warning: variable "stat" was set but never used

t130.cu(24): warning: variable "ldb" was declared but never referenced

$ cuda-memcheck ./t130
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
status = 0
info = 0
devInfoArray = 0
-0.0226168, 0.514827, -4.29722
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

Your code only shows a single array.  If you had a batch of arrays, you would pass an actual array of device-allocated pointers, for each of A and Y.

Based on comments below, here is a version of the code using non-random input:

```
$ cat t130.cu
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cublas_v2.h>

#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    //init id, handle and stat
    int id = cudaGetDevice(&id);
    cublasHandle_t m_cuBLAS;
    cublasStatus_t status;
    // create handle
    status = cublasCreate(&m_cuBLAS);
    std::cout << "status = " << status << std::endl;

    //params
    const int C = 3;
    const int M = 2;
    long lda = C;

    //init variables
    float *Amat, *Ymat, *Xmat;
    float *gAmat, *gYmat;

    //allocate mem
    Amat = (float*) malloc(M * C * sizeof(float));
    Ymat = (float*) malloc(C *  sizeof(float));
    Xmat = (float*) malloc(M *  sizeof(float));

    srand(100);
#if 0
    for (int i = 0; i < C * M; i++) {
        Amat[i] = rand() % 10 + 1;
        Amat[i] = (float)Amat[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < C; i++) {
        Ymat[i] =  rand() % 10 + 1;
        Ymat[i] = (float)Ymat[i];
    }
#endif
    Amat[0] = 6;
    Amat[1] = 7;
    Amat[2] = 6;
    Amat[3] = 5;
    Amat[4] = 5;
    Amat[5] = 5;
    Ymat[0] = 9;
    Ymat[1] = 3;
    Ymat[2] = 10;
    //allocate mem
    cudaMalloc( &gAmat, M * C * sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc( &gYmat, C * sizeof(float));

    //copy mem
    cudaMemcpy(gAmat, Amat, M * C * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(gYmat, Ymat, C * 1 * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    float **ggAmat, **ggYmat;
    cudaMalloc(&ggAmat, sizeof(float*));
    cudaMalloc(&ggYmat, sizeof(float*));
    cudaMemcpy(ggAmat, &gAmat, sizeof(float*), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(ggYmat, &gYmat, sizeof(float*), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    //init info params
    int info = 0;
    int devInfoArray[1] = { 0 };

    //Synchronize (not necesarry I think, but just to test)
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();


    //run cublas
    status = cublasSgelsBatched(m_cuBLAS,
        CUBLAS_OP_N,
        C,
        M,
        1,
        ggAmat,
        lda, //or 1
        ggYmat,
        lda,
        &info,
        NULL,
        1);

    //Output info
    std::cout << "status = " << status << std::endl;
    std::cout << "info = " << info << std::endl;
    std::cout << "devInfoArray = " << devInfoArray[0] << std::endl;

    cudaMemcpy(Xmat, gYmat, C * 1 * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    //Output printed
    std::cout << Xmat[0] << ", " << Xmat[1] << ", " << Xmat[2] << std::endl;

    //free memory
    free(Amat);
    free(Ymat);
    free(Xmat);

    cudaFree(gAmat);
    cudaFree(gYmat);

    //destory handle
    cublasDestroy(m_cuBLAS);

    return 0;
}
$ nvcc -o t130 t130.cu -lcublas
$ cuda-memcheck ./t130
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
status = 0
status = 0
info = 0
devInfoArray = 0
-6.5, 9.7, 0.707106
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

Comment: Thank you for your reaction, it runs now, which is a lot better than before, but when I run the same code as you I get a status 13 response, plus I get the wrong answer. Matlab tells me that the result should be [-6.5, 9.7]. With `A =  [6, 7, 6, 5, 5, 5]` and `Y = [9, 3, 10]; `

Do you think this has to do with the installation then?

Comment: When I run with the A and Y values you suggest, the first 2 output values I get are indeed -6.5 and 9.7 and the reported status is zero.  So if you are getting an error then I think you may have a problem with your setup.  If you have a new CUDA install, it's usually a good idea to verify operation using one or more of the sample codes.  I've updated my answer with this test using non-random values.